# Total price changes to zero after selecting an option

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

I recently updated from Magento 1.6.1 to Magento 1.9.2.1 and I noticed that the total price of a product changes to 0,00 when I select an option (https://sportinngerritsen.nl/professional-supreme-elite-200-mtr-amber). When I continue to my shopping cart, the price is correct. I've tried a few things I found on the internet like changing a peace of code in the file `optionapp/design/frontend/default/sportinn/template/catalog/product/options/view/options.phtml`:

```
price += parseFloat(this.config[optionId][selectOption.value].priceValue);
```

I also compared this to the standard templates (rwd and base), but then I noticed that it doesn't work in these templates either. Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's weird, but I found the solution, without really knowing the answer:
Check if it works in the rwd or base template. 
*Doesn't it work in these templates either?* Download the same Magento version as you're using from the website and replace the rwd and base template. 
*Does it work?* Compare the difference between the rwd/base template and the one that the website is using.